# numbering issues of using Algorithms package

Tags: latex

I am using algorithms package to writing my thesis, and having a question on numbering issue. The thesis is composed of several chapters, and each chapter may include a set of algorithms, procedures and heuristics, and each of which is presented using algorithms package.

After using \floatname to customize the captions, I now have
Algorithm 1.1, Algorithm 1.2, Procedure 1.3 Procedure 1.4, Algorithm 2.1, Algorithm 2.2, Procedure 2.3 Procedure 2.4

This is not the numbering scheme what I want, which should look like

Algorithm 1.1, Algorithm 1.2, Procedure 1.1 Procedure 1.2, Algorithm 2.1, Algorithm 2.2, Procedure 2.1 Procedure 2.2

Can you let me know any hint for doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to define new environments for algorithms and procedures (and heuristics) alike, all calling the algorithms package and use custom counters on both. That way you could increase the two counters separately whenever either is used in your thesis.

For further help on setting custom counters read the [advanced topics section of the wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Topics) or [the blog entry on latex matters covering counters](http://texblog.wordpress.com/2007/07/25/counters-in-latex/).